# Getting an auth error when calling a Grails plugin that uses mongodb

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have created a mongo database plugin for my application. Right now the mongodB does not have any users created. When I run the plugin directly I can successfully run all of my defined CRUD activities. When I include the plugin in my GRAILS application, get a handle to the plugins data service and call any CRUD activity I get:

"serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18

Since I don't have auth defined in my Mongo running instance and since I am successful when running my plugin directly I am confused as to whyu I get an auth error once I have added the plugin to my application BuildConfig and attempt to access it from the app.

any suggestions?

Comment: Does your app have a DataSource.groovy declaration that is overriding one in your plugin? I'm thinking your MongoDB settings are not being read in you app?

Answer (score 0):

when you install your plugin into an app, the plugin's `DataSource` and `Config` are ignored. So you have to repeat the definition of your mongodb-datasource in the main app